# how to avoid race conditions with scala parallel collections

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

Are parallel collections intended to do operations with side effects? If so, how can you avoid race conditions?
For example:

```
var sum=0
(1 to 10000).foreach(n=>sum+=n); println(sum)

50005000
```

no problem with this.
But if try to parallelize, race conditions happen:

```
var sum=0
(1 to 10000).par.foreach(n=>sum+=n);println(sum)

49980037
```

Comment: No, side effects are bad.  If you don't have state, it's much harder to have race conditions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Quick answer: don't do that. Parallel code should be *parallel*, not concurrent.

Better answer:

```
val sum = (1 to 10000).par.reduce(_+_) // depends on commutativity and associativity
```

See also `aggregate`.

Answer (score 5):

Parallel case doesn't work because you don't use volatile variables hence not ensuring visibility of your writes and because you have multiple threads that do the following:

1. read `sum` into a register
2. add to the register with the `sum` value
3. write the updated value back to memory

If 2 threads do step 1 first one after the other and then proceed to do the rest of the steps above in any order, they will end up overwriting one of the updates.

1. Use `@volatile` annotation to ensure visibility of `sum` when doing something like this. See [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html).
2. Even with `@volatile`, due to the non-atomicity of the increment you will be losing some increments. You should use `AtomicInteger`s and their `incrementAndGet`.
3. Although using atomic counters will ensure correctness, having shared variables here hinders performance greatly - your shared variable is now a performance bottleneck because every thread will try to atomically write to the same cache line. If you wrote to this variable infrequently, it wouldn't be a problem, but since you do it in every iteration, there will be no speedup here - in fact, due to cache-line ownership transfer between processors, it will probably be slower.

So, as Daniel suggested - use `reduce` for this.